# VBA + autocomplete date

Tags: vba, date, excel

I have a variable (the value comes from a textbox) which is a date in dd/mm/yyyy format. I want to autofill a few cells, but it changes the year instead of the day. I know it is because it doesn't see it as a date but as a string. But i don't find a wy to make it happen. This are a few tryouts:

```
Sub tryout()

'result: 30/12/2015  30/12/2016  30/12/2017  30/12/2018  30/12/2019  30/12/2020  30/12/2021  30/12/2022  30/12/2023
Range("A1").Value = "30/12/2015"
Range("A1").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:I1"), Type:=xlFillDefault

'result: 30/12/2015  30/12/2016  30/12/2017  30/12/2018  30/12/2019  30/12/2020  30/12/2021  30/12/2022  30/12/2023
Range("A2").Value = "30/12/2015"
Range("A2").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:I2"), Type:=xlFillDefault

'result: 30/12/2015  30/12/2016  30/12/2017  30/12/2018  30/12/2019  30/12/2020  30/12/2021  30/12/2022  30/12/2023
Range("A5").Value = Format("30/12/2015", "dd/mm/yyyy")
Range("A5").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A5:I5"), Type:=xlFillDefault

'result: 30/12/2015  31/12/2015  01/01/2016  02/01/2016  03/01/2016  04/01/2016  05/01/2016  06/01/2016  07/01/2016
Range("A3").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" 
Range("A3").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:I3"), Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

The last one is the one I need, but not with a value from an excel cell, but from a variable.

I hope someone can give me some pointers.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you entering the date into `Range("A1")` as a string?

Try this and let me know if it helps:

```
Sub saas()
    Range("A1").Value = DateValue("30/12/2015")
    Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
End Sub
```

Comment: Wauw, it is that simple! Well, my variable was a string and in my search I didn't found the function DataValue. Well, thank you very much, it works!